# Problem with product page (sidebar goes down)

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupalcommerce (CommerceKickstart 7.x-2.0-rc2). 
There is an issue with the display of the product page. The product page is composed of a content and a right-sidebar. Every page that uses this configuration is well displayed but not the product page : the sidebar goes down. 
First I thought about a css problem but I found that it is a problem with the htlm structure : 
- For good pages the markup "aside", that contains the sidebar", is included in the div "zone-content" that is included in the div "zone-content-wrapper". 
- For product page the markup "aside" is included directly in the div "zone-content-wrapper". 
I looked at the files tpl.php of the theme but found no issue (I don't have a good knowledge about templates...).

Does someone already faced with this issue?

Comment: Try another theme. If the problem is gone then your current theme is the problem. I used drupal commerce before but had no such problems

Comment: I think Kickstart 2.0 doesn't have this problem anymore. Please update & test.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mine is inside an article container. Go to Appearance -> Commerce Kickstart -> Settings -> Zone and Region Configuration and check Content Section -> Content Zone -> Regions.

There should be Sidebar First, Content, Sidebar Second in order. Make sure all of those are in there.

I do know I ran into this issue but mine was CSS related (I changed the width of the content region). Check your settings above and make sure everything looks good. No unassigned regions etc. Try a full wrapper if you don't have one and try without if you do and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you,  but it doesn't work. I tried all what you suggested, the Regions are correctly organized but it didn't work. I changed again the CSS in order to solve the problem but there is still a problem with the html structure. With the developper tools of Chrome I moved the div "aside" into "zone-content" and the page is well displayed so I think it is really a problem with HTML structure. I don't know how to change the HTML structure of this particular page in DrupalCommerce. Does someone has another idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing after updating from Commerce Kickstart RC1->RC4; the problem seems to be caused by a wrong structure of the DIV containers.
The region-sidebar-second should be a child of columns-inner, but on the product page it's on the same level.

The culprit *might* be the template

`profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/commerce_kickstart/commerce_kickstart_product_ui/theme/node--product--type.tpl.php`

Which lacks an opening <div> tag. Copying this file to my at-commerce theme and inserting said tag right after the <article> tag helped.

Caution: I didn't investigate that thing further and I am not sure if the structure of the containers is correct right now!

Comment: @povanh It'd be much nicer if you considered *accepting* the "solution that works for you" - which is done by clicking on the tick mark on the left hand side.